# Update a column with doctrine

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I want to make simple update of a "flag" for status in my database when i clic on button "valided" with doctrine but the value doesn't change.
Just update field status value to 20.
My database :

[image]

Entity demand :

```
/**
     * @var \Status
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Status")
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="status_idstatus", referencedColumnName="id_status")
     * })
     */
    private $statusstatus;


  /**
 * Set statusstatus
 *
 * @param \OrderIT\Bundle\OrderBundle\Entity\Status $statusstatus
 * @return Demand
 */
public function setStatusstatus(\OrderIT\Bundle\OrderBundle\Entity\Status $statusstatus = null)
{
    $this->statusstatus = $statusstatus;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get statusstatus
 *
 * @return \OrderIT\Bundle\OrderBundle\Entity\Status 
 */
public function getStatusstatus()
{
    return $this->statusstatus;
}
```

Controller demand

```
    /**
 * Valid a Demand entity.
 *
 * @Route("/{idDemand}/valid", name="demand_valid")
 * @Method("GET")
 */
public function validAction($idDemand)
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $demand = $em->getRepository('OrderBundle:Demand')->find($idDemand);

    if (!$demand) {
        throw $this->createNotFoundException('Unable to find Demand entity.');
    }

    $demand->setStatusstatus = ('20');
    $em->persist($demand);
    $em->flush();
    return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('listing'));
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are doing it the wrong way... you must insert a status entity into the setter method:

```
public function validAction($idDemand)
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $demand = $em->getRepository('OrderBundle:Demand')->find($idDemand);
    if (!$demand) {
        throw $this->createNotFoundException('Unable to find Demand entity.');
    }

    $status= $em->getRepository('OrderBundle:Status')->find(20);
    if (!$status) {
        $status = new Status();
        $status->setId(20);
        /** or new Status(20) depends on your implementation */
    }

    $demand->setStatusstatus($status);
    $em->persist($demand);
    $em->flush();
    return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('listing'));
}
```

Comment: Why `$em->persist($demand);` ?